# ArrayList random generated

Tags: java, arraylist

Im having a class assignment tonight in some hours, and I can't get mye ArrayList to work.

The whole point is to have a random generated array list (length 12) which shows 12 bets. H, U, B. (H= Home team victory, U= tied, B= away team). We should be able to type in our guesses, and see how many rights we've got! It might be super wrong, but this is my array list code:

```
Public void weekResult();

  private ArrayList<weekResult> weekResults;
  private WeekResult RandomWeekResult;

  public static void main (char [] args)
   {
       ArrayList<weekResult> weekResults = new ArrayList <weekResults>();
       weekResults.add(new WeekResult('H', '1'));
       weekResults.add(new WeekResult('U', '2'));
       weekResults.add(new WeekResult('H', '3'));

       Random r = new Random();
   }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: You are doing nothing with the Random r object.  You create it, but you do nothing with it.

Comment: where am i supposed to bring in the Random r object? and how? :)

Comment: This code is very far from compiling. Review the syntax for classes, modifiers, the naming conventions, the way a main method must be defined. Then fix the compilation errors. Then divide the task in smaller parts. You're supposed to be able to type your guess, but I see no code handling that. Compile evvery time you add a new line to the code. Don't add random stuff without checking that the code compiles.

Comment: the error message i get right now, is that the class "weekResult" can't be found

Comment: @JBNizet i got this code as a way to handle the user to type in his/her guesses:

public char [] register()
{ 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    char [] Tipperekke = new char[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Skriv inn tippetegn "  + (i + 1) + ": ");
        Tipperekke [i] = Character.toUpperCase(scan.next().charAt(0));
    }
    
    return Tipperekke;    
}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually adding items to the arraylist, you need to set up a loop and add variables based off of a random number. The following code does that.

```
for(int x=0;x<12;x++) {
    int randomChoice=r.nextInt(3);
    if(randomChoice==0)
        weekResults.add(new WeekResult('H', '1'));
    else if(randomChoice==1)
        weekResults.add(new WeekResult('U', '2'));
    else
        weekResults.add(new WeekResult('B', '3'));
}
```

Comment: (Actually it doesn't, since you're using assignment operators instead of equality checks :)